# WHERE "OR" HAVING Conditions instead of "AND"

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause, having

i want to run sql query (**mysql**) and i have multiple condition in **WHERE** & also multiple condition in **HAVING**,
**SQL** apply "**AND**" between **WHERE** & **HAVING**, i want to apply "**OR**" between.

WHERE Condition 1,  Condition 2 .... Condition N
{{OR}}
HAVING Condition 1,  Condition 2 .... Condition N

Comment: `HAVING` operates on aggregate rows while `WHERE` operates on single rows. It would be better you include the whole SQL statement since the question doesn't make too much sense as it is.

Comment: The where clause first limits the rows, then the grouping occurs on the rows filtered by where, then finally the having clause filters those grouped rows by filtering on the totals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option that I can see to solve your problem is to separate the query and apply `UNION DISTINCT` to remove the duplicated results. The solution could be something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ...

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT * FROM t1 HAVING ...
```